# Rails 4 / Capistrano error with precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

The following errors now occur anytime I deploy after an upgrade from Rails 3 to 4 and upgrading Capistrano to 2.15.5. It feels like a file permissions thing, but I'm not really sure... Any ideas?

```
  * executing "cd -- /u/apps/myapp/releases/20131224033924 && RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["staging.myapp.com"]
    [staging.myapp.com] executing command
  *** [err :: staging.myapp.com] I, [2013-12-24T03:42:52.799146 #20143]  INFO -- : Writing /u/apps/myapp/releases/20131224033924/public/assets/admin-04eaac91ff9aee71e42df134ddf2f0cd.js
  ...
  ...
  ...
  *** [err :: staging.myapp.com] I, [2013-12-24T03:42:52.799146 #20143]  INFO -- : Writing /u/apps/myapp/releases/20131224033924/public/assets/jquery-10eaac91ff0eee71e42df134ddf2f0aa.js
```

The dots represent every other asset in the repository.

I verified that the assets were created. Also, the app is running fine (there are some issues with restarting some processes via cap after the pre compilation...which might be related)

I am using rbenv which is set up on the ubuntu 13 server using Ansible

Comment: Is permision given for writing for the folder? Also rbenv\rvm configured not correctry? To less information :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't errors.  Capistrano is misleading in that it seems to consider any program output as an error and prefixes it with "err".  That output is sprockets simply saying "this file needs to be written to disk."

See: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb#L133

Comment: super helpful. That makes total sense now. Thank you!

Comment: what exactly needs to be done here? I think I'm having the same problem but that github link is not enough to help me unfortunately

Comment: Not understanding @sixty4bit. There is nothin NF to do. It's normal output for Capistrano.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom hmm ok, I am having a problem with assets while upgrading to Rails 4 (deploying to staging server with Capistrano) where all of the output is red and none of the assets appear on the page when I load it in browser. I made a SO question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115456/upgrading-to-rails-4-assets-not-being-precompiled-red-during-cap-deploy-but